# Loop only iterating once | JS

Tags: javascript

I had this:

```
           for (i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
               temp = elements[i].querySelectorAll(".fill");
               tempArr = Array.from(temp);
               color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
               for (i of tempArr){
                   i.style.backgroundColor = color;
               }
               if (i == 1){
               console.log("hi")
               }
           }
```

It's only iterating once. I had the console log there as a test. I'm not getting any errors back so I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong either.

Comment: I created elements write before the for loop. `var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".category");`

Comment: Hi, the answer below is correct. In the second inner-loop you should use `for (j of tempArr) {}` instead (use `j` instead of `i`). Common mistake that even masters make when we're tired. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting `i` on this line:

```
for (i of tempArr){
```

Use a different variable:

```
for (i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
    temp = elements[i].querySelectorAll(".fill");
    tempArr = Array.from(temp);
    color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    for (j of tempArr){
        j.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
    if (i == 1){
    console.log("hi")
    }
}
```